# How to determine which button was pressed out of three buttons

Tags: ios, ios6, uibutton, uistoryboardsegue

I have three buttons, they all do the same thing perform a segue. All linked to the same connection.

```
- (IBAction)difficultyButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    // Any difficulty selected
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainGameTurnGuess" sender:self];
}
```

What I need to do is determine what button was pressed in the `prepareForSegue` method. How can I tell which out of the three buttons are pressed.

Without looking at the wording/text on the button as this would change for localisation.

Comment: Add a different `tag` value to each.

Comment: I have but how do I reference them in prepareForSegue

Comment: Keep a strong reference to your buttons when you create them

Comment: Hi StuartM, as an aside, have you considered using a UISegmentedController instead of three buttons?

Comment: @Marco - Yes thanks, in this case the buttons makes sense and a segmented controller would not.

Comment: Here I have answered ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978332/how-to-detect-the-pressed-button-and-display-it-on-another-view-objective-c/30931829#30931829

Check if it helps you.

Comment: This is already answered with the tag approach with is much better than bloating out your app delegate with little snippets each time you need functionality like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can ditermine the Taped Button using Tag Value suppose you have tree Button for Example:-

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)  UIButton *btn1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btn2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btn3;
```

Then set Tag of Button like:-

```
btn1.tag=1;
btn2.tag=2;
btn3.tag=3;
```

and set Same `IBAction` for each Button and:-

```
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(difficultyButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(difficultyButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(difficultyButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (IBAction)difficultyButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
 NSLog(@"Button tag is %d",sender.tag);

     // you can use if else condition using sender.tag  like

      if(sender.tag==1)//first button related identifire
      {
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainGameTurnGuess_FirstButtonIdentirier" sender:sender]; 
      }
      else if(sender.tag==2)//second button related identifier
      {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainGameTurnGuess_secondButtonIdentirier" sender:sender]; 
      }
      else   //Third button related identifier
      {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainGameTurnGuess_ThirdButtonIdentirier" sender:sender]; 
      }

}
```

**For Info**

If you are using `id` in `IBAction` then you get the Button Object like:-

```
- (IBAction)difficultyButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"Button tag is %d",button.tag);
}
```

Comment: Your first answer was enough. Thanks for this I needed the pointed to the UIButton for sender to have this working. Previously I was just getting (id)sender, so couldn't access tag

Comment: You don't need to use tags with this setup. Instead of comparing sender.tag == 1, you could just compare sender == btn1, etc.

Comment: @neilco there is multiple alternate way for doing same thing and yes stuarth if you are used (id) then you can get selected button object like  **`UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender`**

Comment: @NitinGohel Indeed, but why go to the trouble of configuring tags when you don't need to. Occam's razor :)

Comment: usually the tag is most safe way for doing this type of task. now this is depend on coder what they think and how to do. :)

Comment: IMO it is easier to tag a button than create an outlet for the button to use as its reference.

Comment: @StuartM Yep, if you do everything in the interface builder, that's true. However, Nitin's answer does everything in code, so setting up the tags is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

store the tag of the button in an instance variable, and look at that variable when prepareForSegue is called

Answer (score 0):

You can forward on the `sender` parameter sent to `difficultyButtonPressed:` as that is the button that was pressed. That is, if you do this:

```
- (IBAction)difficultyButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    // Any difficulty selected
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainGameTurnGuess" sender:sender];
}
```

the `sender` parameter sent to `prepareForSegue:sender:` will be the button that was pressed.

Comment: id is not a Button Object if you are use (id) instead of (UIButton*) in Button IBAction then you must create button object like  **UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;**

Comment: @NitinGohel Incorrect. Try it: Add `NSLog(@"%@", sender)` to the event handler and you will see something like this: `<UIButton: 0x8c4f7c0; frame = (131 187; 59 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c46ed0>>`. You only need to cast `sender` to a `UIButton` if you need to access the properties and methods characteristic of a UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the buttons Restoration Id. In prepareForSegue you can then do the following:

```
UIButton *btnSender;
if ([sender isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
{
    btnSender = (UIButton *)sender;
}

// Then you can reference the Restoration Id or a tag of the clicked button to do further conditional logic if you want.
if([btnSender.restorationIdentifier isEqualToString:@"myBtn1"])
{
   //do something
}
```

I quote the apple documentation:

> Because segues can be triggered from multiple sources, you can use the information in the segue and sender parameters to disambiguate between different logical paths in your app. For example, if the segue originated from a table view, the sender parameter would identify the table view cell that the user tapped. You could use that information to set the data on the destination view controller